# Approximate Cost of Food & Beverage Preparation & Storage Equipment on A350

Tags: airline-operations, airbus-a350

What's the approximate price for all the food and beverage preparation & storage equipment on the A350? If you don't know the answer for the A350, I'm interested in hearing knowledgeable estimates with a 90% confidence interval range.

I'm asking for a research project I'm doing.

In response to the critique that the question is too broad: Food and beverage storage and preparation equipment on large wide-bodies is supplied by just 1 or 2 global suppliers. I wouldn't expect the price to be different by geography since it's all typically denominated in USD. But, if it makes a difference, let's say we are talking about the US market.

For an example, I believe I know the following from prior research:

All the galleys in each A350 cost about \$1-1.3 million USD per A350 aircraft,

All the business class seats likely cost about \$2.6 million in each A350 assuming \$70-80 thousand USD per business class seat multiplied by an estimated 35 business class seats for airlines that choose a 2-class configuration of the A350.

All the oxygen systems in each A350 is roughly \$100-150 thousand.

Assuming a 2-class configuration of the most popular version of the A350, what's the approximate total value of all the food and beverage storage and preparation equipment?  If there are important distinctions or configurations I'm not clarifying, I'd ask you to assume the configuration that is most common since that would be most reflective of the overall market.

Comment: You mentioned the galleys in your question, what equipment are you asking about that isn't included in the cost of the galleys?

Comment: Well, see if you can find the catalogue for the A350. I did a Google search on the galley equipment of the A350 and many pages seem to be pointing at the catalogue which I can't currently find.

Comment: I misunderstood your question at the beginning, you're excluding all labor costs (such as meal preparation, transportation and distribution), only equipment purchasing and maintenance. Correct?

Comment: @Pondlife: examples of specific equipment would include: coffee and espresso makers, water boilers, beverage containers, refrigerators, freezers, chillers, microwave, convection and steam ovens, etc. And yes, I'm only talking about the cost of purchasing all the equipment that would be needed for one A350. None of the ongoing maintenance cost or the labor involved in actually serving and preparing the food.

Comment: This question is too broad.  It might be better if the OP were to ask specific questions about the prices of different foods and beverages (which will depend *very heavily* on airline), and do the math based off of that.  With the fluctuation of pricing for different kinds of food, and the fluctuation of passengers per plane per carrier...  Estimates for this are going to be ridiculously broad.